# About countable set

Tags: general-topology, second-countable, first-countable

Let $f$ be a function in [a,b] with a countable break points (note by $S$). Is it true that the closure of S is countable?

Comment: Take $\textbf{Q}\cap[a,b]$.

Comment: thank you, i think i have weaken it too much, i have edited it :3

Comment: "Break points"? Does that mean, points where $f$ is not continuous?

Comment: @GerryMyerson yess, i'm sorry if my English is not good

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. The rationals are dense so all you need to do is take the rationals in the interval.  The closure is $[a,b]$, which is uncountable.

The answer to your new question is no.  One can construct a function that is discontinuous only at the rationals in the interval.

Let ${c_n}$ be a sequence of positive numbers such that $\sum c_n$ converges.  Put the rationals into sequence, ${x_n}$.  Then define $$f(x)=\sum_{x_n\lt x}c_n$$, where $f(x)$ is zero if there are no $x_n$ to the left of $x$.

$f$ has the required property.

Comment: Another example is $f(m/n)=1/|n|$ when $m, n$ are co-prime integers, and $f(x)=0$ when $x\not \in \Bbb Q$... In general, if $X$ is a metric space with no isolated points and $Y\subset X,$ then there exists $g:X\to \Bbb R$ such that $Y$ is the set of discontinuities of $g,$ iff $Y$ is $F_{\sigma}$ in $X.$